# Stop slider when embedded movie plays.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Slider that I have modifed the code so it stops on mouseover. So far so good. but.. As you can see in the html I have one slider with en embedded video.

My problem is that even though the slider now stops on hover, I also want it to stop when I play an embedded video. Preferably, but not necessary, resume the slider when the video ends.

Javascript:

```
    var VSliderHome = true;
$("#SliderHome").hover(function() {
VSliderHome = false;
}, function() {
   VSliderHome = true;
});

function autoplaySlider(length) {
    if (VSliderHome) {
        if (visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
        visibleSlidePosition += 1;
    } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
        visibleSlidePosition = 0;
    }
    updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
    updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<slider.body>
<section class="cd-hero">
   <ul id="SliderHome" class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">
   <li class="selected">
      <div class="cd-full-width" style="background-image: url(img/fileupload/zlide.jpg)">
         <div class="textcont-left">
            <h2>text</h2>
            <p>text</p>
            <a href="#" class="cd-btn">Köp Nu</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li style="background-image: url(img/fileupload/smatrphones.jpg)">
      <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fXu2fWz" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="cd-half-width">
         <div class="textcont-right">
            <h2>text</h2>
            <p>text</p>
            <a href="#" class="cd-btn">Mer Information</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      </li>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an on-click function in the current function of the slider... Similar to the on-hover,however do it on-click, so that when you click in the area of the PLAY it will effect the slider... even though you're clicking play and the click has nothing to do with the slider, the fact that the video is on the slider and the slider is awaiting an on-click function result... works.

Comment: You thin you could proved an example? i gave it a shot but couldn't get it to work. I even tried to remove the autoplay class on click that requires to make the slider move but it stilled moved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the video event play/pause to change your variable

```
$('video').on('play pause', function(e){

    VSliderHome = e.type === 'pause';

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for events from the video and respond accordingly. You can see the details of how to do this in the [YouTube Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

As a quick example, you might want something like this:

```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      // stop slider
    } else if (done) {
      // start slider
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried to add the True/False functions for the hoverstate, but copuldnt make it work. Unsure if I wrote it wrong, didnt throw any errors though.